# Shutting down Windows from kernel mode?

Tags: winapi, kernel

I'm trying to create a driver that will intercept a certain key sequence and perform a reboot from kernel mode in Windows, similarly to the [REISUB](http://kember.net/articles/reisub-the-gentle-linux-restart/) key sequence in Linux.

I've created a keyboard hook just like [Ctrl2Cap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897578) does, and I've tried calling [`NtShutdownSystem`](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winservergen/thread/b2df4a2a-a083-4d26-abcd-ac59bdcfe407) to reboot the system.

The handler *does* detect the key press, but the problem is that when it actually calls `NtShutdownSystem`, I get a BSOD with the [`ATTEMPTED_SWITCH_FROM_DPC`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff560140(v=vs.85).aspx) error code.

I'm assuming this is because I can't shut down the system from an executing [DPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deferred_Procedure_Call), so I probably need to execute my code from somewhere else.
But I don't know where.

So the question is:

#### How *can* I shut down the system upon detecting the key sequence in kernel mode?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ah, I figured out the answer....

Seems like [`ExQueueWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff540216.aspx) does the trick:

```
VOID NTAPI MyShutdownSystem(PVOID) { NtShutdownSystem(1); }

// ... [code] ...

PWORK_QUEUE_ITEM pWorkItem =
    (PWORK_QUEUE_ITEM)ExAllocatePool(NonPagedPool, sizeof(WORK_QUEUE_ITEM));

if (pWorkItem != NULL) {
    ExInitializeWorkItem(pWorkItem, &MyShutdownSystem, NULL);
    ExQueueWorkItem(pWorkItem, DelayedWorkQueue);
}
```